# Handle event only once when many listeners gets the same event

Tags: java, listener, imap, distributed-system

I have an appication that listens to a mail inbox and processes each incoming mail. The requirement is that this application will have multiple instances for redundancy and for load balancing - one instance will handle the event while the others should ignore it. When i start 2 or more instances all of them are getting the same event and i'm not sure what is the best practice in making just one instance (randomly or round-robin) to handle the event.

I thought about creating a synchroniztion service which will be a Singelton that all the instances should send request to before handling an event and only one of them will receive the OK to handle it while the others will be instructed to ignore it, but i'm not sure if that is the best idea.

I wasn't able to focus my queries online to get relevant info for that issue. 
I would be glad to get any references for articles about this issue or suggestions for best practices for this issue.

Comment: Keep it simple.  Your synchronization service just hands the event to the next instance in a round-robin.  You still have to handle holding the event in a queue when all of the instances are busy.

Comment: If you look at older answers, you'll find people with the same problem and the solution suggested include storing flags on the message and moving the message to another mailbox. Either will work. I'm too lazy to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @arnt How is marking the message with flags or moving it to another mailbox is going to solve my problem? the idea of having multiple instances is that my service will keep functioning even if other instances have crashed. Obviously i need a centralized resource to instruct the instances what to do. I'm just wondering what this reource should be in order to reduce chances of failure and provide reasonable performance.

Comment: And if your central instance crashes?  Same problem.

Comment: @Max Agreed, i'm looking for the best way which minimizes the chance of crashing for the central (Singleton) component.